# Can I write the results of SimpleInjectors diagnostics to a log file?

Tags: .net, ioc-container, simple-injector

Using SimpleInjector I call `container.Verify()` at the end of my configuration, and get the diagnostics information in the debugger as described in [the documentation](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Diagnostics). I would like to write that information to a log file. Is there a way access it programmatically or a way hook a logger or tracer into SimpleInjector?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Writing to a log file seems useful when you need to to analyze what happens in a production environment, but the difference between the DI configuration on your dev box and a production server should hardly be any different, and the diagnostic results will therefore be the same on both your machine and the server.

Comment: We are currently working on opening up the diagnostic API. This will probably be added in the next minor release (v2.4).

Comment: I just pushed an [alpha to NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector/2.4.0-alpha2) that adds a new SimpleInjector.Diagnostics.dll to the core package. You can just call `Analyzer.Analyze(container)` to get a list of all the diagnostic warnings. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Sounds very nice. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Injector 2.4 contains a [diagnostic API](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) (SimpleInjector.Diagnostics.dll) that allow you to query the container for diagnostic warnings. Using this API you can write integration tests that automatically check the configuration for diagnostic warnings:

```
// using SimpleInjector.Diagnostics;

[TestMethod]
public void Container_Always_ContainsNoDiagnosticWarnings()
{
    // Arrange
    var container = Bootstrapper.GetInitializedContainer();

    container.Verify();

    // Assert
    var results = Analyzer.Analyze(container);

    Assert.IsFalse(results.Any(), Environment.NewLine +
        string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            from result in results
            select result.Description));
}
```

Of course, you can also write this to a file:

```
var results = Analyzer.Analyze(container);

File.WriteAllLines("c:\\diagnostic.txt", results.Select(r => r.Description));
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do what I need. Btw if you're interested in having this exposed without resorting to reflection I could take a stab at it and send you a PR.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but this part of the system is internal for a reason. I don't want to make things public unless I'm pretty sure the API is right. For instance, this feature will probably get its own assembly in the future and will change a bit. That's why it's not open right now. I'm sorry if this is of inconvenience to you.

Comment: No problem. I can appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

ContainerDebugView which I guess can be categorized as the Facade class for the Diagnostics mechanism in SimpleInjector is only used as a DebuggerTypeProxy for the Container class.

It's an internal class with a public constructor so you can't construct it without using reflection and the Activator class. If you do that however you should be able to call the constructor with your container and then use the Items property to get an array of DebuggerViewItem which contains the Name, Description etc. of warnings and errors in your configuration.

Hope this helps as I can certainly see why you might want to be able to view the errors without using the debugger. (Eg. in Unit-Tests)